# using variables for the cases and a function for a switch?

Tags: php, case, switch-statement

In PHP I'd like to do this:

```
switch (function_foo($bar,$bar2)) {
case $fu:
    *Do Stuff*
    break;
case $fubar:
    *Do Other Stuff*
    break;
}
```

Is this a terrible idea? Will it work?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Using a function in the `switch` is OK : the function will be called, and will return a value -- which is the one that will be used for the case.

It's exactly the same as writing :

```
$my_var = function_foo($bar,$bar2);
switch ($my_var) {
    // ...
}
```

Even if I prefer using a variable, so the code is easier to read.

And using variables in the `case` is something you don't see often ; but it works fine too ;-)

Quoting [the manual page of `switch`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.switch.php) :

> The case expression may be any
> expression that evaluates to a simple
> type, that is, integer or
> floating-point numbers and strings.

So, your code will work, as long as `$fu` and `$fubar` contain simple-type values.

Using a variable as a `case` value not often done *(as far as I can tell from the code I read)*, probably because some other languages don't allow that *(for instance, C doesn't allow that ; and the `switch`/`case` structure is borrowed from C)* ; but it works :

```
$a = 1;
$b = 2;
switch (1) {
    case $a: echo 'a'; break;
    case $b: echo 'b'; break;
}
```

Will output :

```
a
```

Answer (score 2):

Never tried a function as parameter to the `switch`, not sure (You should give it a try), however you can first store function return value in some variable and use that in `switch` eg:

```
$return_value = function_foo($bar, $bar2);

switch ($return_value) {
case $fu:
    *Do Stuff*
    break;
case $fubar:
    *Do Other Stuff*
    break;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

According to [the manual](http://ca.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.switch.php), a PHP `switch` statement is exactly like a series of `if`/`else if` statements (if every case ends with `break`). That means your technique should work. As long as the function names and variable names are readable, I can't think of any problems with it.

In some other languages, the `switch` statement is actually a performance improvement over `if`/`else if` statements, so you need to know the case values at compile time. It doesn't look like PHP does that kind of thing.

Answer (score 1):

Its posibble yes and its called lambda, which are hidden functions

```
$lambda = function($a, $b) {
    return $a * $b;
};


$return_value = function foo($bar, $bar2){ return $logic }

switch ($lambda(2,4)) {
case $fu:
    *Do Stuff*
    break;
case $fubar:
    *Do Other Stuff*
    break;
}
```